# Codeigniter issue with loop and Condition

Tags: php, codeigniter, loops, conditional-statements

I am loading a view like this

```
if($type == 'view'){
 // do something
}else if($type == 'insert'){
   // Here i am making a form
?>
    <select>  
    <?php 
        foreach($applications as $row)
        {
            ?>
            <option value = "<?php echo $row->id;?>">
                <?php echo $row->name;?>
            </option>  
       <?php } ?>
    </select>  
<?
}else{
    //do some thing else
}
```

Now this is the error i am encountering:

**Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ELSE in url on line xx**

The weird thing is that if i comment out the loop if works fine. What is the problem and how can it be resolved?

Comment: Would you mind pasting the entire code snippet and tell us which line the error is occurring on? I just executed the code you posted and I am not getting a syntax error, so it might be caused by something else in the code you have not posted.

Comment: Do you have short tags enabled on your server? I noticed sometimes your using `<?` and other times `<?php` to open your php tags. Should probably stick to using one :)

Comment: no short tags is not a problem i have already checked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use codeigniter **loops in view way** like this:

```
<?php foreach ($applications as $row):?>
     <option value = "<?php echo $row->id; ?>">
                    <?php echo $row->name; ?>
                </option> 
    <?php endforeach;?>
```

Comment: Did this work? I write my for loops with {} and have never had a problem using them in views in codeigniter...

Comment: But why does it work, as opposed to using other formats of foreach ?

Comment: It's a built-in codeigniter way to work with foreach loops. take a look [here](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/views.html) at the **Creating loops** section.

Answer (score 0):

It works fine for me... try again

```
<?php

if($type == 'view'){
 // do something
}else if($type == 'insert'){
   // Here i am making a form
?>
<select>  
   <?
   foreach($applications as $row){
   ?><option value = "<?php echo $row->id;?>"><?php echo $row->name;?></option>  
   <?php
   }
   ?>
</select>  
<?
}else{
    //do some thing else
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your want like this code:

```
<?php
if ($type == 'view')
{
    // do something
}
elseif ($type == 'insert')
{
    // Here i am making a form
?>
    <select>  
<?php
    foreach($applications as $row)
    {
?>
    <option value = "<?php echo $row->id;?>"><?php echo $row->name;?></option>
<?php
    }
?>
    </select>  
<?php
}
else
{
    //do some thing else
} 
?>
```

Comment: That's incorrect. `else if` and `elseif` will be considered the same by the parser when using curly brackets. And he is using curly brackets.

Comment: I'm sorry, yes you are correct with `else if` and `elseif`, then why your code not working?

Answer (score 0):

Using switch, you have a more elegant way of code writing and of course faster, try:

```
switch($type){
 case 'view':
  //do something
 break;

 case 'insert':
  echo '<select>';
     foreach($applications as $row){
      echo '<option value="'.$row->id.'">'.$row->name.'</option>';
     }
  echo '</select>';
 break;

 default:
  //do something else
 break;
}
```